# Why I get XML Parsing Error: no root element found (even if I compare primitive types like the Inner Exception requires)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firefox, xml-parsing

When trying the following, I get the XML Parsing Error: no root element found in Firefox. In Internet Explorer, I don't get the error but it just does not work like I expect.

```
   IList<Gu> gus = Context.GuSet.Where(gu => gu.Id == id).OrderBy(gu=>gu.User.Name).ToList();

            IQueryable<UserModel> users = TabWebContext.UserSet.Select(o => new UserModel
            {
                Id = o.Id,
                UserName = o.Name,
                SomeBoolean= gus.Where(gu => gu.User.Id == o.Id).FirstOrDefault().SomeBoolean
            }
```

The inner Exception of my ServerLog is:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'XY.Z.Gu'. Only primitive types or enumeration types
>   are supported in this context.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, ConstantExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.T
>   ...
>
> .... ...MyController.cs:line
>   531

I understand that the Entity Framework does not know how to translate a comparison of two entities into SQL.
But the Ids which I compare are primitive types (integer) which should work.

Comment: I would say your tags should not have firefox or xml-parsing included (as you're not *attempting* to do any parsing), and should really include Entity Framework as that's your *actual* error by the looks of it....  I've taken a stab at an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the XML issue is just that your controller code is crashing and whatever (lack of?) exception handling means it's simply not sending sensible HTML back to the browser.  Ignore that for now - if you fix the EF problem it'll probably go away.

I'm guessing EF doesn't like the projection part, trying to work out how to translate your existing IList<> into something it can use in SQL. you could work around it by doing this, though that wouldn't end up with an IQueryable<> at the end of course (which may or may not be a problem depending on your amount of data and specific use case)

```
IList<Gu> gus = Context.GuSet
  .Include(gu=>gu.User)//make sure the User property is hydrated - this might have been your actual problem?  not 100% sure though
  .Where(gu => gu.Id == id)
  .OrderBy(gu=>gu.User.Name).ToList();

//first get a list of users.
var users = TabWebContext.UserSet.Select(o => new UserModel
{
    Id = o.Id,
    UserName = o.Name
})
//fetch into List<UserModel> - note the DB will now get hit HERE
//with something like "select id, name from users"
.ToList();

//as users is now a List<UserModel> we can iterate over it and change each entry.
users.ForEach(u=>
  //Set SomeBoolean for each UserModel entry based on 'gus' list.
  //also note now dealing with case where FirstOrDefault returns a null
  //object and using default of false if it does.
  u.SomeBoolean=gus.FirstOrDefault(gu => gu.User.Id == u.Id)?.SomeBoolean ?? false);
```

This should *work*, but will evaluate the actual SQL query at an earlier point than your code would (as you were just directly getting `IQueryable<>` it would have only hit the DB when you first tried to *do* something with `users`)